# Right Management Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, permissions, powershell, security

I have a sharepoint list. Users should be able to create new items and change some attributes. I gave full access for the users on the list items. But now I think there is a security gap:

> what about if some users try to change the items via powershell? Than
>   they would be able to work on the items without controll and without
>   the special forms and without the buisiness inteligence.

Who to handle such situations? Is there a away to deny access via powershell to some users? (one user needs to have access via powershell because the workflow starts some PS-scripts).

Comment: Can you please explain how and why end users would be using powershell to manipulate SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT give end users access to the Server or PowerShell

But denying them that will not prevent users from adding list items without using your forms. If they have access to the lists they can use client side object model (or tools developed using these)

If you want control of what enters the SharePoint list you need to control that by the field types, validation on the list. Or if that's not enough write an event receiver.

Comment: So users are always able to make changes on the list with out using the website? So you mean I have to control everything from validation? And how to deny the powershell access?

Comment: If user want and have the knowledge (google) they can always circumvent the web site. By default only farm admin can use SharePoint powershell cmdlets

Comment: But they can't use the objectmodel and so on by default?

Comment: They can only use the (server) object model if they can get the code to run on one of the Servers which they shouldn't have access to. But client side object model/REST can be used from anywhere (if they have the permissions to add list items)